# doesn't receive result when integrate with actions on google even it's received in dialog flow console

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am developing cloud function that use the calendar API to list the event from the calendar and parse the response to get the summary 
I test my function on the dialog flow console beside and it give me the result  that I want but when I integrate it with actions on google It's always go to the catch

/----- read the description for event

```
//----- read the description for event
function getKeyPoint (agent) {
      return fetchDescription(agent.parameters.date,agent.parameters.time).then(() => {
      agent.add("The key point for the requiered event is "+keyPoint);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log("Error here  "+err);

    agent.add(`There is no description  `);
        });
}

function fetchDescription (date,time){
appointmentDuration = 1;// Define the length of the appointment to be one hour.
dateTimeStart = convertParametersDate(date,time);
dateTimeEnd = addHours(dateTimeStart, appointmentDuration);

return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  console.log("is listing now ");
calendar.events.list({
  auth: serviceAccountAuth,
  calendarId: calendarId,
  timeMin: dateTimeStart.toISOString(),
  timeMax: dateTimeEnd.toISOString()
},(err,calenderResponse)=>{
if (err || calenderResponse.data.items.length==0){
  reject(err || new Error('No event at  this time '));
}else {
var calenderResponseBody = calenderResponse.data;
var events=calenderResponseBody.items;
keyPoint  = events[0].description;
resolve(keyPoint);
}
});
});
}



the package : 
{
  "name": "DialogflowFirebaseWebhook",
  "description": "Firebase Webhook dependencies for a Dialogflow agent.",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "semistandard --fix \"**/*.js\"",
    "start": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1",
    "googleapis": "^27.0.0",
    "actions-on-google": "2.2.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.4.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it throwing an error?

Comment: I edit the question and print the error it give me
RangeError: Invalid time value,,,,
even it's worked in the dialog flow console !

Comment: It's the first time that testing in the both dialog flow and actions on google be different, It's always the same result !

Comment: You should print what values you get, and verify that they are defined